# Ошибка при установки пакета Python psutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

У меня Python 3.9.0 версии хочу установить пакет psutil но не получается помогите пожалуйста

проверил пакеты у меня нету пакета psutil, при установки выдается ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: psutil ещё не собрали для 3.9, подождите или ставьте 3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитав эту статью https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/INSTALL.rst установил Visual Studio по ссылке https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/preview/ и смог установить пакет psutil

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]